# Extracting archive to root - Swift

Tags: software-installation, tar, archive, extract

I'm trying to install Swift on ubuntu 16.04; I've downloaded the archive and am ready to extract it, though I'm not entirely sure where I should extract it to.
I was considering simply extracting it to `root`, as the archive contains a `usr` folder, which contains folders `bin`, `include`, `lib`, etc..
I.e which seems to correspond to the folders already there.

My question is, is that the right thing to do, to extract it into root? Will this not delete/overwrite any folders there, or will it simply merge them?

Apologies, I've been using ubuntu for years but I still don't know where to install things!

Comment: Don't Swift has an installation guide on their site where you downloaded the archive ? Or try to google "How to install swift"

Comment: yeah, but they only say that if you're not installing to root then you need to change environment variables - my question is more is it dangerous to extract folders with the same name as pre-existing folders to root?